# Generate & Expire coupon-codes/promo-codes

Tags: php, mysql

We are making a lottery website. In which we want to generate some coupon-codes/promo-codes. Is there any tried and tested code written which generates coupon-codes and expires them after exact 24hrs? We are using (PHP/mySQL).

Thanks in advance.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely, which makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance or support consider mentoring and coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: actually i've written the code which is generating the coupon codes, but i don't know how to handle the expiration thing.

Comment: You need to give us *something* to work with, like even an example schema means we can quickly tailor an answer to what you've got, rather than having to spend time guessing what you might have, where we're bound to guess completely wrong and give you something useless. Context is important here, so if you have some code, share a minimal amount that gives us an understanding of the concrete problem you're facing and make an attempt, regardless of how far you actually get, which shows us the direction you're trying to head. We can fill in the blanks much more easily that way.

Answer (score -1):

There is. It's called `time()` and is inside every single PHP distribution.

To expire a token, you need 2 steps:

- On creating the coupon you call `time()` which generates an integer and add the number of seconds you want the token to be valid to it, then store the result in an unsigned int field called `expires`
- On checking a token you compare this stored value with the current output of `time()` - if the latter is bigger the coupon has expired.

You can clean up expired tokens with `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE expires<UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, but I would not recommend going this route naively, as it will rob you the possibility to differentiate between an expired and an inexistant token.